# What architectural pattern(s) does react follow?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, architecture, frontend, web-frontend

I'm pretty new to React and I have been wondering about what the Architecture of it is? MVC - MVVM?

I've searched on the web, but I haven't yet found an answer that can clearly get to a pattern definition

Answer (score 0):

It is the V (view) from  MVC as far as i know.